# Asymptotic integration of this expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

Any tips how I can find asymptotic decay rate of $f(t)$ below? I suspect it's $O(t^{-\frac{1}{11}})$

$$g(x,t)=\frac{1}{10 (x+1)^{11/10}} e^{\frac{t}{50 (x+1)^{11/5}}-\frac{t}{10 (x+1)^{11/10}}}$$
$$f(t)=\int_0^\infty g(x,t)\mathbb{d}x$$

Using `AsymptoticIntegrate` returns unevaluated:

```
g[x, t] = E^(t/(50 (1 + x)^(11/5)) - t/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10)))/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10));
f[t_] = AsymptoticIntegrate[g[x, t], {x, 0, Infinity}, t -> Infinity]
```

---

Motivation: it's continuous mean-field approximation to SGD, if $i$-th eigenvalue is $O(i^{-11/10})$, $f(t)$ gives loss after $t$ steps.

```
p = 11/10;
z = Integrate[(x + 1)^-p, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];
d[x_] = (x + 1)^-p/z;
loss[x_, t_] := Integrate[u[x, t] d[x], {x, 0, Infinity}];
eqn = D[u[x, t], t] == (-2 d[x] + 2 d[x]^2) u[x, t] + 
    d[x] * loss[x, t];
initialCondition = u[x, 0] == d[x];
g[x_, t_] = 
 u[x, t] /. 
  First@Flatten@DSolve[{eqn, initialCondition}, u[x, t], x, t];
f[t_] = Integrate[g[x, t], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $t\to\infty$ only large $x$-values contribute to the integral. We can therefore neglect the first term in the exponential:

```
g[x_, t_] = E^(t/(50 (1 + x)^(11/5)) - t/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10)))/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10));
gapprox[x_, t_] = E^(-t/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10)))/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10));

f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[x, t], {x, 0, ∞}]
fapprox[t_] = Integrate[gapprox[x, t], {x, 0, ∞}];

Asymptotic[fapprox[t], t -> ∞]
(*    (10^(1/11) Gamma[1/11])/(11 t^(1/11))    *)
```

Check that the approximation works:

```
LogLogPlot[{f[t], fapprox[t]}, {t, 1, 10^4}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[t^(1/11) f[t], {t, 0, 10^4}, GridLines -> {{}, {(10^(1/11) Gamma[1/11])/11}}]
```

[image]

Comment: background for this problem is given [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)

Answer (score 4):

**Workaround** to get **Asymptotic** at: $t\to \infty$ .

```
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

g[x, t] = E^(t/(50 (1 + x)^(11/5)) - t/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10)))/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10));

int = IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][E^(
t/(50 (1 + x)^(11/5)) - t/(10 (1 + x)^(11/10)))/(
10 (1 + x)^(11/10)), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}], z, z == (1 + x)] // ExpandAll

int2 = IntegrateChangeVariables[int, w, w == z^(11/10)] // ExpandAll

M = MellinTransform[E^(t/(50 w^2) - (a*t)/(10 w))/(11 w^(12/11)), a, s](*Assumed: a = 1 *)

int3 = Integrate[M, {w, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {s > 0, t > 0}]

S = Series[int3[[1]], {t, Infinity, 1}] // Normal(* Order 1 ! *)

A = InverseMellinTransform[S, s, a] /. a -> 1 // Simplify(*Asymptotic, Solution: *)
```

$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{\frac{t}{50 (1+x)^{11/5}}-\frac{t}{10 (1+x)^{11/10}}}}{10 (1+x)^{11/10}} \, dx\approx \frac{(-1)^{5/11} \left(-100 i e^{\frac{1}{50} \left(t+5 i \sqrt{-t^2}\right)}
   \sqrt[22]{-t}-2 i \sqrt[22]{2} \sqrt[11]{5} t \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{22}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{22};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{t}{8}\right)+2^{6/11} \sqrt[11]{5} t^{3/2} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{6}{11}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{6}{11};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{t}{8}\right)\right)}{44 t^{23/22}}$

We can check:

```
Table[{NIntegrate[g[x, t] /. t -> 10^n, {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20], N[A /. t -> 10^n, 20]}, {n, 1, 7}] // 
 Re // Quiet // MatrixForm
```

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov To get simpler asymptotic you may: `Simplify[ComplexExpand[Series[A, {t, Infinity, 1}] // Normal // Re], 
  t > 0] // Expand`.

Comment: thanks! btw, motivation for this problem is given [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)